# Autoincrement MySQL Column with Pandas

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, null

I've done a bit of googling, and I can't find much information on this. I have a MySQL table that I'm pushing data to that has a key column. The only writing to this table is from my python script. I know you can use "auto-increment" columns to keep the key generation a sanitary process. I also know that when you insert into the table using normal MySQL, you're supposed to push a SQL `NULL` in to the row to get it to auto-increment properly. How would I set up the rows to have the proper `NULL`? Can I use pandas `NaN`s or `NoneType`s?

E: Here's a sample setup.

```
Table: Logbook
| Key | Date  | Notes      |
|  1  | 02-18 | Successful |
|  2  | 03-18 | Failure    |
```

Using SQL to insert to the table:

```
INSERT INTO Logbook
VALUES (NULL, 04-18, Failure)
```

I want to accomplish this with `pd.to_sql`

Comment: "you're supposed to push a SQL NULL in to the row to get it to auto-increment properly." What?

Comment: What does 'push a sql null' mean?

Comment: As in, when you `INSERT` into the table (as if you're executing a query), the value that goes in to the column that is auto incremented is NULL.

Comment: Why would there be a need to set the auto-increment field as `NULL`?

Comment: Because that's how it auto-increments? If I push a value, then it resets the autoincrementing from that value.

Comment: Auto increment resets unless you pass a null value?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html "No value was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL assigned sequence numbers automatically. You can also explicitly assign 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers, unless the NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO SQL mode is enabled. If the column is declared NOT NULL, it is also possible to assign NULL to the column to generate sequence numbers."

Comment: "When you insert any other value into an AUTO_INCREMENT column, the column is set to that value and the sequence is reset so that the next automatically generated value follows sequentially from the largest column value."

Comment: In other words, the auto-increment will never be reset to 0, it will only be reset to a *higher* value if at all.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.